# pygame start menu not rendering when the program starts

Tags: python, menu, pygame, screen

I'm currently learning pygame and writing a simple 2d game. I've come to the point when I need to introduce a start menu. The problem is though the startSCreen function doesn't render the "press space to start" label when the program is started but it does after the character dies for the first time (as can you see below, the function runs in an infinite loop, startScreen is recalled again after the player loses). The way the game works is displayed below:

```
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 900))
pygame.display.set_caption('The Game')
start_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25, bold = True) 
def startScreen():
    start = True
    while start:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            mainGame()
            start = False
    win.fill((0,0,0))

    start_text = start_font.render('PRESS SPACE TO START', 1, (255, 255,    255))
    win.blit(start_text, (50, 300))
    pygame.display.update()

def mainGame():
    main game code

while True:
    startScreen()
```

I didn't paste the mainGame function code as I doubt it affects the issue. Hope somebody can spot the mistake :).

Comment: Is the lack of indentation in the while loop simply a copy/paste error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that until you run `mainGame()`, `start=True` and only when you've run the game does `start` become False. However, the "press space to start text"'s placed after the loop therefore it will only run once the loop has been exited (which means you have played the game at least once.

To solve this problem simply place the display code before the loop as shown below:

```
def startScreen():
    # Display Start Text
    win.fill((0,0,0))

    start_text = start_font.render('PRESS SPACE TO START', 1, (255, 255,    255))
    win.blit(start_text, (50, 300))
    pygame.display.update()

    # Loop until exited or game is played
    start = True
    while start:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                mainGame()
                start = False
```

Comment: It works the way it should now. Thank you for enlightening me :)